# how to import jar files in linux machine

Tags: java, linux, smtp, compiler-errors

I am trying to run a Java program on Linux machine, that includes:

```
import javax.mail.*;
```

I have included `mail.jar` into `myjdk/lib`.  Even on compiling it shows errors like

```
javax.mail does not exist
```

What to do?

Comment: Are you aware of the -jar option?

Comment: Can you post more information about the errors that are shown?

Comment: Are you moving from Windows to Linux, or have you started development on Linux? And what do you do with the files in the "lib" directory>

Comment: I am developing a program for SMTP using java api

Comment: I have done it on windows but now I am asked for do the same on linux

Answer (score 1):

On bash run this command

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path/to/my.jar
```

and then compile

Comment: This is a bad idea. If you rely on the classpath being set in the environment, your program or build will fail if you go to another machine or add another programmer to the project. Worse, you can build/run with incorrect JAR versions.

Comment: but now I have to program the same on linux due to some requirments , in eclipse I have added that mail.jar and activation.jar but now I dont know how to do so opn linux

Comment: Aren't you using Eclipse on Linux too?

Comment: @parsifal - the **reason** for using the CLASSPATH variable is to facilitate migration between between systems with different file layouts!

Comment: @symcbean - that's not a good reason. Perhaps you've been lucky enough never to work on a project where developers had different CLASSPATH environment variables. I've been unlucky too many times.

Answer (score 1):

Check your CLASSPATH. Make sure it points to all JAR files in the directory. This should be specified by either a direct path to the your JAR, or a wildcard.

Take a look at this page on setting the class path: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: how to chk classpath on linux?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I'm going to assume that you have a script to construct the classpath from the files in the "lib" directory.

In that case, the most likely problem is that Windows uses a semi-colon (";") as a classpath separator, while Linux uses a colon (":").

Offhand, I don't know of a solution that works in both environments. The usual approach is to create a "runme.sh" for Linux, and a "runme.bat" for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all your jar files and .java files in same folder.
To compile,

```
javac -cp .:mail.jar SendEmail.java
```

To execute,

```
java -cp .:mail.jar SendEmail
```